# Best practices of writing mutation fields in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

Let's assume, that I have this model structure:

```
User {
  id: int
  group: UserGroup
}

UserGroup {
  id: int
  name: string
  users: User[]
}
```

I want to have possibility to do these actions:

- create users group
- edit group data
- add user to group
- remove user from group
- remove all users from group

What I want to ask is: **what is the best practice for creating fields for such operations in GraphQL?** I'm thinking about some possible options (maybe there are other ones):

**1. Many simpler fields**

In here, many fields will be added. One field references a single action mentioned above. So this is relatively simple.

```
createGroup(groupId: Int!, name: String!, users: Array<User>): Group
editGroup(groupId: Int!, name: String, users: Array<User>): Group
addUserToGroup(groupId: Int!, user: User!): Group
removeUserFromGroup(groupId: Int!, userId: Int!): Group
removeAllUsersFromGroup(groupId: Int!): Group
```

**2. Resource fields**

In here, fields reference model resources. So in regards to our example, there should be only two of them:

```
createGroup(groupId: Int!, name: String!, users: Array<User>): Group
editGroup(groupId: Int!, name: String, users: Array<User>): Group
```

But in case of `editGroup` node, users list is always overwritten. So in the front-end code, there is always a "must" of having a complete list of users. We all should know, that this can be a little overwhelming to implement this. Especially when having lists with many items or not having the whole list in particular part of the system.

**3. Resources fields and operation custom type**

```
UsersMutationType {
  operation: (ADD|DELETE|DELETE_ALL)!,
  users: Array<int>!
}

createGroup(groupId: Int!, name: String!, users: Array<User>): Group
editGroup(groupId: Int!, name: String, users: UsersMutationType): Group
```

So in here, a separate type will be created. This type will tell what users operation should be done (if even should). In here, we eliminate the problem of loading a whole list of users for particular group. So, if we want to remove single user, we just define `operation` as `DELETE` and add user id to `users`. If we want to remove all users, we leave `users` empty, and set `DELETE_ALL` as operation value.

Sooo... back to the question. What is the best practice in regards to above topic? Should we create many simpler fields, or is it better to do this with the other presented ways?

Comment: I like the thought that went into this question, but I think it's ultimately opinion-based. Some of those patterns are more intuitive to me than others as a consumer of the API, but that's largely my preference. I'd be hard-pressed to find concrete reasons not to implement one pattern or another, outside of the trade-offs already described.

Comment: Best practices for GraphQL are still evolving. Your best bet might be to take a look at a mature, existing API like [Shopify's](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/reference/mutation).

Comment: Shopify's published GraphQL Design Tutorial has a section on this exact question. It provides some guidance but really also ends up at the answer "it depends": https://github.com/Shopify/graphql-design-tutorial/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#manipulating-relationships